# CE certification for changing USB port

Tags: usb-c, certification, ce

I have a CE certified product that uses USB micro port.
In lieu with EU requirements that all products must use USB-C port, do we need to apply for get a new certification for CE if we change the USB port only?

Comment: Have you checked the relevant directive to see if the directive actually applies to your product? The classes are fairly specific and certainly do not include everything with a USB port.

Comment: Have you checked that you are required to modify a product that's already on the market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must. The certification is no longer valid if you modify anything on the product.

CE regulations require you to keep a technical file on the product at the disposal of the inspection authorities, in EU. The product cannot be modified because it would be different from the technical file.